# Maintain checkbox state after postback

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, gridview

I have a parent *gridview*. In that, I have multiple *nested gridviews*. In each *nested gridview* I have column in which a header checkbox and child checkboxes are present. If I check one *nested gridview*'s header checkbox and again checked another *nested gridview*'s header checkbox then first *gridview*'s checkboxes does not maintain its checked status. They become unchecked including header checkbox.

I am using the following code

```
$(document).ready(function () {

        $("#<%=grdParent.ClientID %>").each(function () {
            alert("Hi");
            $(this).find(".grdchild > tbody > tr").each(function () {
                $(this).find('input:checkbox[id*="chkHeader"]').click(function () {
                    var isChecked = $(this).prop("checked");
                    $(this).closest("tr").find("[id*=chkChild]:checkbox").prop('checked', isChecked);
                    //$("[id*=chkChild]:checkbox").prop('checked', isChecked);
                });
                //Do Stuff
            });
        });
    });
```

Comment: what is the code behind ? maybe there the check boxes change again to initial state...

Comment: No,i'm not using any code behind.i'm trying to do with jquery or javascript.

Comment: Please attach jsfiddle with proper DOM structure.